# is it possible to decrease the string character after replace a string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
    |US3973996|0|0|0|0|US8008573|
|US6162985|0|0|US8309838|US8008573|
```

then I use

```
df_select['pat_num'] = df_select['pat_num'].str.replace('\|+', ',')

df_select['pat_num'] = df_select['pat_num'].str.replace('0', '')

df_select
```

for removing the '|' and '0' and the result is shown as below

```
  ,US3973996,,,,,US88573,
US6162985,,,US839838,US88573,
```

but I want to see the result being like this

```
,US3973996,US88573,
US6162985,US839838,US88573,
```

how to decrease multi,,,,, into single, ?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Building on your code, here's one option that chains two `replace` calls and one `strip` call.

```
df['pat_num'].str.replace('0', '').str.replace(r'\|+', ',').str.strip(',')

0             US3973996,US88573
1    US6162985,US839838,US88573
Name: pat_num, dtype: object
```

---

`extractall` might give you better mileage:

```
df['pat_num'].str.extractall(r'(US\d+)')[0].groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)

0              US3973996,US8008573
1    US6162985,US8309838,US8008573
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

This, and the `findall` option below both make use of the structure of your IDs as "USXXXXXXX" (whatever `(US\d+)` captures).

---

In similar vein, you may also use `findall` and join the sublists:

```
df['pat_num'].str.findall(r'(US\d+)').str.join(',')

0              US3973996,US8008573
1    US6162985,US8309838,US8008573
Name: pat_num, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
df[0].str.split('|').apply(lambda x: ','.join([j for j in x if j and len(j) > 2]))
```

**Output**

```
0              US3973996,US8008573
1    US6162985,US8309838,US8008573
Name: 0, dtype: object
```